# Know if operation succeeded or rejected with promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have a main function where I want to check if a record exists or not in order to create or update the record, so in this function I am calling a helper function that checks for that record using ajax call, and then I want a true/false to be returned to the main function, but do I return defrred.resolve() and deferred.reject(), and how do I check on them? I can't seem to be able to implement it in promises.

Here's my code below, any hint is appreciated.

```js
   function _mainFunction()(
        var recordID = prompt("Enter Desired Record ID");
        var promise =  _helperFunction(recordID);
        promise.then(...) //do some processing when the reocrd is created or updated
)
        
        
   function _helperFunction(passedId){
   if (passedId) {
            if (!_isRecordExists(passedId)) {
              // if record doesn't exist, create it.
            }
        }
   }



    function _isRecordExists(passedId){
        var decision;
        var baseUrl = "some url";
        var dfd = $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        });
        dfd.promise().then(
            function(data, status, jqXHR){
                decision = true;
                dfd.resolve();
            }, 
            function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                decision = false;
                dfd.reject();
            });

        return decision; // do I return decision here for true or false?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return promise object from `_isRecordExists` function. Then in `_helperFunction` if-block wouldbe transformed into success/error callbacks of the promise returned from the previous check:

```
function _mainFunction() {
    var recordID = prompt("Enter Desired Record ID");
    var promise = _helperFunction(recordID); 
    promise.then(function() {
        console.log('Do something else');
    }, function() {
        console.log('Failed to find and create new. Maybe try again');
    });
}

function _helperFunction(passedId) {
    return $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
        if (passedId) {
            _isRecordExists(passedId).then(function(recordObj) {
                // record exists, do something with it
                console.log('Exists');
                deferred.resolve(recordObj);
            }, function() {
                // record doesn't exist, create it.
                console.log('Does not exist');
                deferred.reject();
            });
        }
        deferred.reject();
    }).promise();
}

function _isRecordExists(passedId) {
    var decision;
    var baseUrl = "some url";
    return $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });
}
```

Here is also a rewritten `_helperFunction` implemented with a real promises (either with a polyfill or native):

```
function _helperFunction(passedId) {
    if (passedId) {
        return Promise.resolve(_isRecordExists(passedId)).then(function(recordObj) {
            // record exists, do something with it and pass further
            return recordObj;
        }, function() {
            // record doesn't exist, create it
            return createNewRecord(); // createNewRecord should return new promise
        });
    }
    return Promise.reject();
}
```

Comment: You should return the promise from `_helperFunction` as well, or line 4 will throw an error.

Comment: so if the record doesn't exist, it means that the query failed, and it goes into the fail call back, so there I can call the create function? Is it a good practice to call functions to create stuff on fail? sorry am still newbie in this.

Comment: @user5699896 yes, this is normal if it fits your needs. Just using jQuery for promises is not very good idea, it's really not really suited for this.

Comment: Check updated answer. It's fine if you use something like this. Otherwise it would make sense to rewrite it with real Promises, either native (no IE yet, use polyfill) or with a promise library.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function _mainFunction(){
        var recordID = prompt("Enter Desired Record ID");
        _helperFunction(recordID)
            .then(function(decision) {
                // you can use decision here
            })
            .catch(function(decision) {
                // passing decision as true or false in _isRecordExists fn, just for information
                // or future usages
                // then / catch status already gives the idea
            });
    }

   function _helperFunction(passedId){
        var deferred = $.deferred();
        if (passedId) {
            _isRecordExists(passedId))
                .then(function(data) { 
                    // then means exists : do whatever you want here
                    // if you want to return the result as promise;
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                 .catch(function(errorData) {
                    // catch means does not exist : create or do anything
                    deferred.reject(errorData);
                 });
        } else {
            // no id provided
            deferred.reject();

        }
        return deferred.promise();
   }

   function _isRecordExists(passedId){
        var decision;
        var baseUrl = "some url";
        var dfd = $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        });
        return dfd.promise().then(
            function(data, status, jqXHR){
                decision = true;
                dfd.resolve(decision);
            }, 
            function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                decision = false;
                dfd.reject(decision);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not a jquery guy, there might be syntax error on deferred creation but, think this as a pseudocode just for giving the idea

Answer (score 0):

Syntax errors at `function _mainFunction()(` , close of `_mainFunction()` at `)` ; jQuery promise object not returned from `_helperFunction`

```js
function _mainFunction() {
  var recordID = prompt("Enter Desired Record ID");
  var promise = _helperFunction(recordID);
  promise.then(function success(t) {
      // resolved 
      console.log(t)
    }, function err(e) {
      // rejected
      console.log(e)
    })
    //do some processing when the reocrd is created or updated
}

function _helperFunction(passedId) {
  if (passedId) {
   // return `_isRecordsExists`
   return _isRecordExists(passedId)
      .then(function(data) {
        return data
      }, function err(data) {
        return data
      })
  } else {
    // if `passedId` not entered, return rejected deferred 
    return $.Deferred().reject("no passedID")
  }
}

function _isRecordExists(passedId) {
  var decision;
  var baseUrl = "some url";
  // do asynchronous stuff
  // var dfd = $.ajax({
  //      url: baseUrl,
  //      type: "GET",
  //      contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
  //      headers: {
  //          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
  //      }
  //    });
  var dfd = $.Deferred(function(d) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      d.resolve()
    }, Math.random() * 2000)
  });
  // return `dfd` promise here
  return dfd.promise().then(
      function(data, status, jqXHR) {
        decision = true;
        return decision
      },
      function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        decision = false;
        return decision
      })
    // return dfd.promise(); 
    // do I return decision here for true or false?
}

_mainFunction()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   function _mainFunction() {
        var recordID = prompt("Enter Desired Record ID");
        var promise =  _helperFunction(recordID);
        promise.then(...) //do some processing when the reocrd is created or updated
}
        
        
   function _helperFunction(passedId){
   if (passedId) {
            if (!_isRecordExists(passedId)) {
              // if record doesn't exist, create it.
            }
        }
   }



    function _isRecordExists(passedId){
        var decision;
        var baseUrl = "some url";
        var dfd = $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        });
        dfd.promise().then(
            function(data, status, jqXHR){
                decision = true;
                dfd.resolve();
            }, 
            function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                decision = false;
                dfd.reject();
            });

        return decision; 
        // do I return decision here for true or false?
        // answer: NO!!, before the value(true or false) is assigned to decision, decision is returned...(Of course, the value may be allocated and then return). The Promise object should return to the place where the actual value is used.
    }
}


   // here is my answer
   function _mainFunction(passedId){
       var recordID = prompt("Enter Desired Record ID");
       isExistPromise = _isRecordExists(recordID);
       isExistPromise.then(function(data){
           if (data.isExist) {}
           else {}
       });
   }

    function _isRecordExists(passedId){
        var decision;
        var baseUrl = "some url" + passedId;
        return $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        });
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

> then I want a true/false to be returned to the main function

You can't return true/false to the main function because by the time your code finish execute, the promise is still working and does not have a result yet, hence your `_mainFunction` does not know if it should return true or false.

What you can do is return a Promise in `_mainFunction` and then use `.then` or `.fail` to do your logic code.

```
function _mainFunction()(
    var recordID = prompt("Enter Desired Record ID");
    var promise =  _helperFunction(recordID);
    promise.then(function (result) {
       if (result == true) {
          // Do something
       } else {
          // Do something else
       }
    })
)

function _helperFunction() {
    return $.ajax(...)
            .then(function (response) {
                if (...) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
}
```

From what I observe in your code, I think you should really spend sometime on learning how to work on asynchronous programming in JavaScript.

These are the helpful links that you might want to read:

- [Asynchronous JavaScript Programming](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/)
- [An introduction to jQuery Deferred / Promise and the design pattern in general](http://www.danieldemmel.me/blog/2013/03/22/an-introduction-to-jquery-deferred-slash-promise/)

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you tell me what did you observe in my code that I can improve?

Comment: The `_isRecordExists` function and `decision ` shows me that you still thinking in synchronous programming, or "procedure programming" (like C, or Pascal). You should read the articles I mentioned in my answer to know how to correctly write your code and getting familiar with asynchronous in JavaScript. Good luck.

Comment: Anyone who down voted my answer can please tell me why?